.NET Aspire : how can I remove an migration that has already been applied to the database using Entity Framework Core
I'm working on a .NET Aspire project that includes:

A PostgreSQL component with Entity Framework Core using code-first approach
A persistent data volume
A separate background service for applying migrations (based on https://github.com/dotnet/aspire-samples/tree/main/samples/DatabaseMigrations)

I can successfully add migrations using:
dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate

The background service then applies these migrations to the database.
However, I'm encountering issues when trying to remove a migration that has already been applied. I've attempted to use:
dotnet ef migrations remove --force

But this doesn't affect the database. How can I properly remove an already applied migration in this setup? Am I missing something?
I would like to remove the migration that has already been applied through .NET Aspire
